# PrimeFaces password validation

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I have some trouble understanding this PrimeFaces showcase:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="matchGrid" cellpadding="5">                   
    <h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Password 1: *" />
    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{passwordView.password5}" match="pwd2" label="Password 1" required="true" />

    <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Password 2: *" />
    <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{passwordView.password5}" label="Password 2" required="true" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

In particular, I do not understand, why the value binding of both input fields point to the same property `password5`.

If I follow this example, but add some validation for password strength

```
@StrongPassword
private String password5;
```

I get duplicated validation messages on this constraints (for both fields). This is not the intended behaviour, I'd expect

- the content of the first input field to be validated for password strength and
- the content of the second input field to be validated for equality with the content of the first field

How to achieve this?

Comment: i need to try, it may typo. will it work if we keep different properties for password match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there doesn't seem to be a need to record the second input in the view bean, I didn't add another property for it and just removed the value binding:

```
<p:password id="pwd2" label="Password 2" required="true" />
```

This gives the desired result. The content of the second field is also preserved on validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to validate two passwords to equals in Primefaces `<p:password` component is to use attribute `match`, you could put it to your main input password input form and indicate id of your second checking input form (Id of another password component to match value against - from Primefaces docs).

Let me show you an example:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="matchGrid" cellpadding="5">

    <p:outputLabel for="usPassword" value="Password:"/>

    <p:password id="usPassword" value="#{authBean.password}"
                required="true" placeholder="Password"
                requiredMessage="Error: enter your password"
                match="usPasswordConfirm"/>

    <p:outputLabel for="usPasswordConfirm" value="Repeat Password:"/>

    <p:password id="usPasswordConfirm" value="#{signupBacking.password}"
                required="true" placeholder="Repeat Password"
                requiredMessage="Error: repeat your password"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Here I used `match="usPasswordConfirm"` and the same id value has the second password input form, so Primefaces will check both typed values for a match